# Python Folium - Toggle off city boundary after a few seconds

Tags: python, leaflet, maps, gis, folium

Is there a way to automatically toggle off the city boundary after a few seconds? I tried using time.sleep() however it did not work. Thank you so much.

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrUO.png):

```
import folium
import os
import time

m = folium.Map(location=[22.3193, 114.1694], zoom_start=10, tiles='CartoDB Dark_ Matter', zoom_control=False, height='75%')

outline = os.path.join('outline.json')

folium.GeoJson(outline, name='outline', show=True).add_to(m)
time.sleep(1000)
folium.GeoJson(outline, name='outline', show=False).add_to(m)

folium.TileLayer('CartoDB Dark_Matter').add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB Positron').add_to(m)


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')
```

[This is the Folium Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmlLV.png)

Comment: All Python code is executed before it generate HTML with map so using `sleep` is totally useless. `folium` runs in web browser and uses `JavaScript`. It needs to use `JavaScript` function `setInterval()`  or `setTimeout()` to execute your `JavaScript` function with delay.

Comment: putting code as image is only waste of time. We can't copy it to test problem and create solution. So we can only downvote it and close question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the best route is to try to do this within the Python code, but rather, with a JavaScript function within the resulting HTML file.

This should be the starting py file:

```
import folium
import os

m = folium.Map(location=[22.3193, 114.1694], zoom_start=10, tiles='CartoDB Dark_ Matter', zoom_control=False, height='75%')
outline = os.path.join(some_path, 'outline.json')
folium.GeoJson(outline, name='outline', show=True).add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB Dark_Matter').add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('CartoDB Positron').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save('map.html')
```

Then, at the end of the resulting HTML file, simply add the following `setTimeout()` function:

```
...

        L.control.layers(
            layer_control.base_layers,
            layer_control.overlays,
            {"autoZIndex": true, "collapsed": true, "position": "topright"}
        ).addTo(map);
        tile_layer.remove();


        // here is our new function, set to remove the GeoJSON layer after 3 seconds
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            map.removeLayer(geo_json);
            }, 3000);

        
</script>
```

Just make sure your variable names match, my HTML file looked like this, but yours will surely be different:

```
        setTimeout(function(){
            map_50c065d5877245f6ba25bdee213bf5fa.removeLayer(geo_json_39ca0b100615423f86a124836b41fa2e);
            }, 3000);
```

At the very beginning of the script element, Folium chooses a name for the map:

```
<script>    
    
            var map_50c065d5877245f6ba25bdee213bf5fa = L.map(
                "map_50c065d5877245f6ba25bdee213bf5fa",
                {
                    center: [22.3193, 114.1694],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 10,
                    zoomControl: false,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );
```

...and later on, it names your 'outline' layer. Here's what my HTML looked like:

```
function geo_json_39ca0b100615423f86a124836b41fa2e_add (data) {
    geo_json_39ca0b100615423f86a124836b41fa2e
        .addData(data)
        .addTo(map_50c065d5877245f6ba25bdee213bf5fa);
```

Answer (score -1):

You may write the javascript function in your html source file,not only in the python script. The python folium package only can achieve some fundmental work. May you need process the html.

Comment: it is good for comment but not for answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).